# how iterate and change the value of a variable inside a while loop in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, variables, while-loop

i'm trying to implement the Halley's method to solve quartic equations in tensorflow using a while_loop and variables. Basically i need to iterate several times, but when i use those Variables in tensorflow it looks like after its assigned a value to the variable, isn't a variable anymore and now turn as a tensor. How can i modify this in that way that a variable can be iterated inside a while_loop taking different values?.  thanks for your help

```
import tensorflow as tf 

tol = tf.constant(0.001, dtype = tf.float32)
x = tf.constant(0.1, dtype = tf.float32)
Coef = tf.constant([1, 1, -1, 7, 2], dtype = tf.float32)
x_nueva = tf.Variable(0.0, name = 'x_nueva')
error = tf.Variable(1.0, name = 'error' )
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
def halley(tol, x, Coef, error, x_nueva):
a0 = Coef[0]
a1 = Coef[1]
a2 = Coef[2]
a3 = Coef[3]
a4 = Coef[4]
x_nueva.assign(x + a0)
error.assign(tf.abs(x-x_nueva))
return error, x_nueva

def condicion(tol, x, Coef, error, x_nueva):
return tf.less(tol, error)

with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init_op)
resultado = tf.while_loop(condicion, halley, [tol, x, Coef, error, x_nueva])
print(resultado[4].eval())
```

tensorflow display the following error related to the variable "x_nueva" :

'Tensor' object has no attribute 'assign'

i guess, after the "tf.assing" , "x_nueva" turns into a tensor and not a Variable, but i can't find how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need variables to do this. In most cases (if not all), using variables within a [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) is incorrect. What you have to do is return on each iteration the values that will be used for the next. The `loop_vars` should only be those that change across iterations. In your case, you can implement Halley's method like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf 

tol = tf.constant(0.001, dtype = tf.float32)
x = tf.constant(0.1, dtype = tf.float32)
# Coefficients are assumed to be sorted from highest to lowest degree
coef = tf.constant([1, 1, -1, 7, 2], dtype = tf.float32)
error = tf.constant(1.0, dtype = tf.float32)

def halley(x, coef):
    # Size of coef must be statically known when using polyval
    coef = tf.unstack(coef)
    # Evaluate polynomial and derivatives
    f = tf.math.polyval(coef, x)
    coef1 = [c * (len(coef) - i) for i, c in enumerate(coef[:-1], 1)]
    f1 = tf.math.polyval(coef1, x)
    coef2 = [c * (len(coef1) - i) for i, c in enumerate(coef1[:-1], 1)]
    f2 = tf.math.polyval(coef2, x)
    # Compute new x and error
    x_nueva = x - (2 * f * f1) / (2 * f1 * f1 - f * f2)
    error = tf.abs(x - x_nueva)
    # Return values for next iteration
    return x_nueva, error

def condicion(tol, error):
    return tf.less(tol, error)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    resultado = tf.while_loop(
        lambda x, error: condicion(tol, error),
        lambda x, error: halley(x, coef),
        [x, error])
    res_x, res_error = sess.run(resultado)
    print(res_x)  # Final x value
    # -0.27295828
    print(res_error)  # Final error
    # 0.0
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i learnt a lot from your code. however  the final error its not consistent , you know that its a numerical approach so the error can't be zero. i guess the problem is about the internal amount of decimal numbers tensorflow admit.

Comment: @JohanR Note the "error" here (as you have defined it) is the difference between two consecutive iterations, being zero in this case means that the last computed increment was smaller than the precision of the computation. If you change `tf.float32` to `tf.float64` in the code you will see a non-zero value. And if you evaluate the polynomial for `res_x` (e.g. with NumPy, `np.polyval([1, 1, -1, 7, 2], res_x)`), you will see it is not exactly zero either.